# Set path to location of tags file

Tags: tags, path

I think this is not *quite* a duplicate, although it's close.

I often work with multiple, slightly different, checkouts of the same multi-directory project. I'd like to be able to jump around using tags and gf, always staying within the current checkout, without having to type anything at startup.

There is a different tags file at the top-level directory of each checkout. The checkouts are numerous and their locations far from static, so hard-coding in paths is not an acceptable solution.

A simple

```
set tags=tags;/
```

seems to work acceptably for the tags part. But to get gf to work I need to append the location of the tags files thus found (notably including the top-level directory) to the path somehow. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Even though the location is not static, for a given checkout they are fixed to a specific location?  I'm wondering if you couldn't setup a sort of "Per Project vimrc" but instead set one up per checkout.

Comment: See http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2944/can-i-load-different-tags-per-project - fugitive.vim + .git/tags = different tags per project

Comment: @jecxjo This would work, but would be difficult for me to set up since I work on a large multi-developer project controlled by mostly emacs users, who would not allow me to commit the .vimrc to the top-level directory.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
let &path += fnamemodify(tagfiles()[0], ':p:h')
```

should add the path of your `tags` file's parent directory to the `path` option.

Updating `path` each time you enter a buffer is probably a good idea:

```
augroup UpdatePath
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead,BufEnter * set path&vim | let &path += fnamemodify(tagfiles()[0], ':p:h')
augroup END
```

Comment: This looks good, but I get "E734: Wrong variable type for +=" when I include it.